# pygame physics simulation symmetry breaks

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, physics, collision

I made a simulation that calculates the elastic collision and gravity between planets. 
It was fine at first, but as we go on, the *symmetry* breaks down at some point. [Here is the Video](https://youtu.be/rj8L2kHFc3M) (break at 1:40) 
I tried with a lot of codes, but the symmetry eventually breaked.

Here is elastic collision code:

```
@staticmethod
def reflect_colliding_circles(a, b):
    delta = vector(a.rect.center[0], a.rect.center[1]) - vector(b.rect.center[0], b.rect.center[1])
    d = delta.length()
    mtd = delta * ((a.radius+b.radius)-d)/d

    im1 = 1 / a.m
    im2 = 1 / b.m

    a.pos += mtd * (im1 / (im1 + im2))
    b.pos -= mtd * (im2 / (im1 + im2))

    v = a.vel - b.vel
    vn = v.dot(mtd.normalize())
    if vn > 0.0:
        return

    i = (-1 * (1.0 + E) * vn) / (im1 + im2)
    impulse = mtd.normalize() * i

    a.vel += impulse * im1
    b.vel -= impulse * im2
```

And Here is gravity code:

```
def calc_gravity(self, otpl):
    force = self.pos - otpl.pos
    if force == vector(0, 0):
        return vector(0, 0)
    distance = force.magnitude()
    force = force.normalize()
    strength = -(G * self.m * otpl.m) / (distance ** 2)
    force = force * strength
    return force
```

The Full code is [here](https://github.com/mcsim415/PhysicsSimulation) 
Why it happen and how to fix it? 
I think maybe it is float's accuracy error, It's just my guess.. 
Thanks! 
(Sorry for my poor English, I used translator a little bit..)

Comment: To me it looks like they are hitting the side of the screen. Can you try to disable collision with the screen boundaries and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: Still no problem solved..

Comment: Btw, you do have a decent amount of logic errors in your code that prevent it from being a true gravity simulation (e.g. it should be  `vel  += dt*acc`, `pos += dt*vel` and you should take a look at [fixing your timing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591949/in-pygame-normalizing-game-speed-across-different-fps-values/13592134). But I am not sure if those are actually the reason for this bug.

Comment: But I am  not sure if there is anything you can do to actually fix this: This is a chaotic system, and any small error might lead to any arbitrary large error later on. That little asymmetry might already happen early on on some call to `.normalize`, caused by floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I used delta time. But if there is a delay, it will pass through the planet it supposed to collision.