# Processing speed changes turtle animation speed

Tags: python, performance, game-physics, turtle-graphics

I was learning python turtle module.

And I was trying to make a simple pong game.

Here is the code:

```
import turtle
import win32api

wind = turtle.Screen()
wind.title("Pong game")
wind.bgcolor("black")
wind.setup(width=800, height=500)
wind.tracer(0) # stops window from updating automaticly



# racket1
racket1 = turtle.Turtle()
racket1.speed(0)
racket1.penup()
racket1.color("blue")
racket1.shape("square")
racket1.goto(-370, 0)
racket1.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)

# racket2
racket2 = turtle.Turtle()
racket2.speed(0)
racket2.penup()
racket2.color("red")
racket2.shape("square")
racket2.goto(370, 0)
racket2.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)

# ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.penup()
ball.color("white")
ball.shape("circle")
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 0.2
ball.dy = 0.2

# score writer
scw = turtle.Turtle()
scw.penup()
scw.speed(0)
scw.hideturtle()
scw.goto(0, 210)
scw.color("white")
scw.write("Blue: 0                  Red: 0", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"), align="center")


# racket 1 functions
def racket1_up():
  y = racket1.ycor()
  if y < 200:
    y += 0.3
    racket1.sety(y)

def racket1_down():
  y = racket1.ycor()
  if y > -200:
    y -= 0.3
    racket1.sety(y)

# racket 2 functions
def racket2_up():
  y = racket2.ycor()
  if y < 200:
    y += 0.3
    racket2.sety(y)

def racket2_down():
  y = racket2.ycor()
  if y > -200:
    y -= 0.3
    racket2.sety(y)

# scores
p1 = 0
p2 = 0


while True:
  wind.update()

  # ball move
  ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
  ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

  # border check
  if ball.ycor() > 239: #240
    ball.dy *= -1

  if ball.ycor() < -239: #-240
    ball.dy *= -1

  if ball.xcor() > 389: #390
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    p1 += 1
    ball.dx *= -1
    scw.clear()
    scw.write(f"Blue: {p1}                  Red: {p2}", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"), align="center")

  if ball.xcor() < -389: #-390
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    p2 += 1
    ball.dx *= -1
    scw.clear()
    scw.write(f"Blue: {p1}                  Red: {p2}", font=("Arial", 24, "bold"), align="center")

  # ball and madareb collision
  if ball.xcor() > 350 and ball.ycor() < racket2.ycor()+60 and ball.ycor() > racket2.ycor()-60:
    ball.dx *= -1

  if ball.xcor() < -350 and ball.ycor() < racket1.ycor()+60 and ball.ycor() > racket1.ycor()-60:
    ball.dx *= -1

  # racket 1 movement
  w = win32api.GetKeyState(0x57)
  s = win32api.GetKeyState(0x53)

  if w < 0:
    racket1_up()
  if s < 0:
    racket1_down()

  # racket 2 movement
  u = win32api.GetKeyState(0x26)
  d = win32api.GetKeyState(0x28)

  if u < 0:
    racket2_up()
  if d < 0:
    racket2_down()
```

The game worked properly but the ball speed changes, I think that this is due to the change of the processing speed changes.

So is it possible to make the speed not change with the changing of the processing speed?

Comment: I don't think there will be a convenient way to achieve this with turtle. You should use a game library that is designed for such things, like Pygame. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591949/in-pygame-normalizing-game-speed-across-different-fps-values

Comment: Use `ontimer` rather than a hard `while True:` loop that just slams the CPU as hard as it possibly can.